# After upgrading to Glass Mapper 5, unable to globally enable lazy loading

Tags: glass-mapper

In the implementation using **Glass Mapper 4.3.x**, I was enabling `Lazy Loading` in `GlassMapperScCustom`:

```
public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver(){
            var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();

            config.EnableLazyLoadingForCachableModels = true;

            var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);

            var factory = dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory as AbstractConfigFactory<AbstractObjectConstructionTask>;
            factory.Remove<ModelDepthCheck>();

            return dependencyResolver;
        }
```

This hid some recursive model references and sloppy model properties.  I am looking for an easy way to re-enable before doing a large re-factorization.

Is this possible in Glass Mapper v5?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In version 5 config.EnableLazyLoadingForCachableModels setting **was removed** and "IsLazy"-setting **was removed** from all model property configuration, like

```
[SitecoreChildren(IsLazy = false)]
IEnumerable<ISitecoreItem> Children{get;set;}
```

You should just remove all these settings from your models, because of in V5 lazy loading was improved (it is enabled by default and disabled when request or model is cachable) and your model cann`t be a mix of lazy and non-lazy parts.

In version 5 you can force disable/enable lazy loading only when you retrieve your model, like

```
var data = _mvcContext.GetDataSourceItem<IData>(x => x.LazyDisabled());

or

var data = _sitecoreService.GetItem<IData>(Constants.Data.ID, x => x.LazyEnabled());
```

Almost all glassmapper interfaces has this parameter.

But I think that for your case it will be enough just to remove old settings when you upgrade to version 5 (at least there were no troubles on our project).

These links may be helpful:

http://glass.lu/Mapper/GettingStarted

http://glass.lu/Blog/V5

Comment: Thanks.   This is a case of, "Don't fight it, just rewrite it."  I have been working on removing recursive model properties and data expensive model properties.  Its a few days worth of work but no getting around it.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use more than one such methods at the same time? For instance if I want LazyDisabled, but also InferType()?