# How to get children of an item via glass mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper

I am building a navigation component using glass mapper. The problem I am facing is not being able to get children items of a navigation item.

Right now I am only getting Parent navigation items.

This is my model:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{127AF5CF-4170-4E43-A8CC-DB89591954E2}", AutoMap = true)]

public class NavigationItem
{
    public NavigationItem()
    {
        ChildNavigations = new List<NavigationItem>();
    }

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
    public virtual Link Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Is Excluded")]
    public virtual bool IsExcluded { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
    public List<NavigationItem> ChildNavigations { get; set; }
}

    public ActionResult RenderNavigation()
    {
        var mvcContext = new MvcContext();

        var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse("{64121195-F56F-4A8B-B8F9-5A1E69BA62FD}"));

        IEnumerable<NavigationItem> navigationItems = currentItem.Children
            .Where(O => O.TemplateID.Equals(ID.Parse("{127AF5CF-4170-4E43-A8CC-DB89591954E2}")))
            .Select(x => mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<NavigationItem>(x));

        return View(navigationItems);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are using Glass Mapper v4.

In order to fix your problem change your definition of ChildNavigations to this:

```
[SitecoreChildren(IsLazy = false)]
public virtual IEnumerable<NavigationItem> ChildNavigations { get; set; }
```

There was a change for v5 and you need to do it differently:
http://glass.lu/Mapper/Documentation/UpgradingToV5

Comment: Doesn't the property also need to be `virtual`?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Glass Mapper. Please let me know what should I change in my code?

Comment: For Glass Mapper 5 take a look here -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16530/after-upgrading-to-glass-mapper-5-unable-to-globally-enable-lazy-loading