# Return Sitecore Items as tree

Tags: sitecore-api

Is there any possible to return a item children as tree? I tried to use GetDescendants however, all items are returned at the same level as a list.

Example:

```
-FORM
    ITEM1
    ITEM2
        ITEM2.1
        ITEM2.2
              ITEM2.2.1
        ITEM2.3
    ITEM3
        ITEM3.1
```

Comment: Use foreach of item.getchildren() to get this results

Comment: Do you want to get all Descendants of the specific item as Tree in objects?

Comment: Did you check Glass Mapper possibilities for your purpose? It can map items with children's. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16553/how-to-get-children-of-an-item-via-glass-mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you want to display the items and if you aren't iterating the whole sitecore structure you can get the child items recursively:

```
public static Result ChildrenRecursive(Item item)
{
    var r = new Result();
    var itemChildren = item.Children;
    r.Items.AddRange(itemChildren);
    foreach (Item i in itemChildren)
    {
        if (i.HasChildren)
        {
            r.Items.AddRange(ChildrenRecursive(i).Items);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

You would need to modify the above code to suit your needs, for example if you need to have a tree object you would need a custom object with subitems properties in order to simulate the sitecore tree.

If you need to read over 100 items I would suggest building a solution using content search and setup indexing for your items.